# React-Native Android Application crashing at runtme

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

My react-native android application is crashing at runtime with following stacktrace error.

```
7-12 13:03:14.714 14231-14231/com.grabonrent.grabonrent E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.grabonrent.grabonrent, PID: 14231
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: com.facebook.react.uimanager.IllegalViewOperationException: Trying to add unknown view tag: 84
                                                                            detail: View tag:1
                                                                             children(2): [
                                                                           82,83,
                                                                            ],
                                                                             viewsToAdd(1): [
                                                                           [2,84],
                                                                            ],

                                                                               at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext.handleException(ReactContext.java:311)
                                                                               at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedFrameCallback.java:31)
                                                                               at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:134)
                                                                               at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame(ChoreographerCompat.java:105)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:869)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:616)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

I am not able to understand what's the error and how to resolve. Please help me with this error

Comment: Don't you have any clue of where could be the error to post some code?

Comment: And, does the app crash on iPhone too or only happen in Android?